# What should we do with the geometry and computational geometry tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

In a similar scope to my [previous](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/what-should-we-do-with-the-meshing-mesh-generation-tags) question, there is a geometry and a computational geometry tag... Should we merge them or keep them separate, but with synonyms.  Furthermore, under what conditions is it more appropriate to merge over create tag-synonyms?  I have seen CFD and Fluid Dynamics placed as synonyms.  What criteria was used to say that it was better to place them as synonyms over merging them altogether?

Comment: If you think of tags as search keywords, I would believe synonyms are better than merging as the diversity of terms reflects the various different approaches, temrinologies of communities that essentially use the same topic.

Comment: I think I agree that we should stick to synonyms where possible.